# Gnome 3.10 doesn't show login, Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: gnome, login, ppa

I use gnome as default desktop. And I recently upgrade Ubuntu to 13.10 then upgraded gnome to 3.10. Upon restarting, it brings me to the gnome log in screen (GDM) and all I see is the top banner part so like your date, music volume, option to restart, suspend or shutdown.

Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> tells me gnome display manager will log out - it does but still nothing.

I am on the log in screen, but there is no user to select, like there normally is or was. I can boot into safe mode and drop down to shell but I am not sure what commands I would enter to get the login screen back. I am using the gnome PPA's and the "unstable" PPA, so I expected issues, but not this - ideas?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1236749/+attachment/3923306/+files/Zrzut%20ekranu%20z%202013-11-28%2017%3A11%3A35.jpg ?

Answer (score -1):

(re)install gdm:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

and choose gdm, works for me.
Best, R.

Comment: did not work for me. If anybody has a solution, please share.